# Change uilabel text after uiview is loaded

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uilabel, iboutlet

I have a custom `UIView` subclass. I am loading this through `[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"" ...]`. I have linked all of my outlets properly in Interface Builder but in `initWithCoder`, my `UILabel` is 0x0.

Where can I have a method that will call when the `IBOutlets` will finish initalizing so I can access my `UILabel` and call `setText`?

Comment: Yes, this is for a custom subview, not a UIViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, found the answer!

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
```

Thanks to all that answered anyway!

Answer (score 1):

viewDidLoad, and don't forget to call super

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   mylabel.text = @"yadayadayada";
}
```

Comment: oh wait, that's for a view controller. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize you UI elements in controller's `-viewDidLoad` method